# Is bitcoin bonus and cloud mining real?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, currencies, exchange-software, crypto-2.0

I received an email saying I have so much money from a cloud mining app that I set up using my phone and the app connected with my IP address.. I didn't really pay to much attention to  the app so I just set the account up and left it like that but where the app was connected to my phones IP address it has been cloud mining for 364 days and I have gained 1.31 in bitcoins and I needed to withdraw it soon but I'm not sure how to do that.. So I been on there messing with it and some how my funds has been sent to SWIFT, what is SWIFT can someone please let me know asap.. Thank you for your time and support

Answer (score 0):

I got the same thing oi nice you have a Bitcoin account you deposit money you buy bit coin the y oi u just pay theme then the will say they can't sent all you money once beacouse is too much money they asked you again to pay another fee you pay then they waited a little they tell you for not pay taxes in you Bitcoin you have to rent an account it like 96$ a day then they disappear they don't talk to you any more and just got scammed by f 100$ I hope my God is going ng take care all of them some how karma is a bitch