How to use a wallet. transactions, addresses, signing, verifying, receipt, collection
I have a transaction ID it
has 630 transactions on it.A lot of them are confirmed but they have the same address they're supposed to be going to it's full. I don't know how to sign and verify correctly. That particular address cannot handle anymore how do I put in more addresses for the same receipt and do I have to collect them all at the same time I don't know any of these things and I'm trying to get help please


I don't know any of these things and I'm trying to get help

Using a wallet (basics)
The basic actions using any wallet, such as Electrum, include

Initial set-up.
When you first use any wallet program, it will create some secret numbers
that are used for creating addresses etc. You can regard these secret
numbers as the main part of a set of data also called a wallet.
A wallet program manages wallet data.
It is very important that you either make a backup of this wallet data and
keep it somewhere safe or write down the private keys or the recovery
phrase and store them safely where no one else can see them. Anyone
who finds these can create a new wallet that has control over all money
sent to your wallet in the past and in the future.

Receiving money
A wallet usually has a button or menu-item to "receive" money. Typically
this generates a new address. You give that new address to someone who
intends to send you Bitcoin money. You don't need to do anything else.
Your wallet talks to a few other Bitcoin nodes and finds out when there
is a transaction paying to your new address. You don't need to do anything
to receive or collect Bitcoin money. You can receive money when your
wallet is turned off. This is because money is kept track of in a list of
transactions called the blockchain and each wallet either keeps its own
copy or can get access to a copy.

Spending money
In the Bitcoin world, spending money means creating a transaction to send
Bitcoin to another Bitcoin wallet. This might be to the wallet of someone
selling a car or it might be sending to the wallet of someone who exchanges Bitcoin money for Canadian dollars they pay to you separately.



Things the wallet does automatically when needed
Signing
When you spend money, your wallet automatically signs the transaction it creates. You don't get involved.
Verifying
Your wallet automatically verifies information about transactions that it receives from nearby Bitcoin nodes (other people's wallets etc). You don't have to do any verifying yourself. It is part of the work the wallet does internally.
Collecting
Bitcoin money is never collected, that isn't the way it works.
If you  want to exchange Bitcoin for US dollars or for Japanese Yen, you typically send Bitcoin to an online currency exchange that accepts Bitcoin.
Beware of fake exchanges.

About Transactions and Addresses
A transaction-Id identifies exactly one transaction. One transaction-Id can never have 630 transactions on it.
A Transaction, identified by a Transaction-Id, could pay money to 630 different recipients by paying 630 different addresses in a single transaction. This is very typical of how Exchanges pay money. it saves them money (Bitcoin transactiuon fees) to join hundreds of payments into a single transaction. 1 transaction with 630 outputs is cheaper than 630 transactions each with 1 output. So if, for example, I paid an exchange some Icelandic Króna to but Bitcoin, they might tell me the transaction-Id of a transaction that paid me, to the address I gave them,  as well as paying hundreds of their other customers. I could check this transaction-Id on some of the many Blockchain Explorers to see if my address is listed. Alternatively I could enter into the explorer the address I gave the exchange and see if the explorer shows any transactions that paid to that address. Even without me doing any of this, my wallet should tell me I have received money.
An address could have 630 transactions that have paid money to that address.

So when. The transaction is confirmed how do I get it to show up in my wallet and how do I turn it int.o Cash USD and transfer out. This is from mining I left a phone on or two or three I don't know I had a lot of phones back that anyway it covers like 6 months and like they're like 3 cents four cents seven cents and the one transaction receipt has 630 transactions on it I didn't know anything about addresses I gave it one of my addresses and it sent supposedly sent a bunch of them to that but I it doesn't show up

I am pretty sure it has never been possible for one person to mine Bitcoin on just a phone - they just aren't powerful enough. Phone mining has to be a scam. For example see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/117009/is-bitcoin-bonus-and-cloud-mining-real
